# ErrImageNeverPull when deploying to Minikube

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kubernetes, minikube

Created a simple MVC app in VS2019. Created a Dockerfile and ran docker build successfully.

Was able to successfully run with:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name mvc2 mvc2
```

browsing to localhost:8080 opens up mvc home page.

Issue is that when I deploy to minikube I get **ErrImageNeverPull**

My deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mvc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mvc
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mvc
        imagePullPolicy: Never # <-- here we go!
        image: mvc2:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you missed performing the `eval` of Minikube Docker env (`eval $(minikube docker-env)` on Unix like but, since you're running Win, `minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression`) before creating the Docker image.

So, right now, you have two options:

1. copy the `mvc2:latest` image using the [Docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) command
2. build the `mvc2:latest` image using the Docker environment variables in order to get it saved on *Minikube*.

Comment: YES!!. that worked. Thanks so much :).  Spend a whole day trying to figure it out